Pages not rendering Laravel, Inertia, Vue JS project on local environment
I have an issue where on my local dev environment in my Laravel, Inertia, Vue JS application when navigating in the app say I click a link to a new like navigate from dashboard to team directory.. or from dashboard to values page etc.. the URL changes in the browser correctly but the content from the new page will not load until I do a manual refresh of the page
Or say in a vue component I click a drop down and then another thing is supposed to populate based off that selection. the item that is supposed to populate does not populate.
The app works perfectly fine on production no issues with navigation. Just for some reason on my local environment the page refuses to load unless I manually refresh it. I came across this issue before and I resolved it by just deleted the entire project and re-setting up my entire environment. I did that again for this project but did not seem to resolve the issue this time. Updated Node and composer. Checked and double checked the config files and I just don't know what is going on. Any help with understanding what is happening here would be a huge help. Like again everything seems to work fine Inertia loading bar goes across the screen as expected the URL changes in the browser as expected to the right page but does not show contents until I manually hard refresh the whole page.
Here is vite config:
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';


export default ({ mode }) => {

    process.env = {...process.env, ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '')};
    const host = process.env.APP_URL.replace(/(^\w+:|^)\/\//, '');
    const homedir = process.env.HOME;

    return defineConfig({
        plugins: [
            laravel([
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ]),
            vue({
                template: {
                    transformAssetUrls: {
                        base: null,
                        includeAbsolute: false,
                    },
                },
            }),
        ],
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                '@': '/resources/js/'
            }
        },
        server: {
            hmr: {host},
            host,
            https: {
                key: `${homedir}/.config/valet/Certificates/${host}.key`,
                cert: `${homedir}/.config/valet/Certificates/${host}.crt`,
            },
        }
    });
}

here is app.js:
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';

import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css';


import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress';

const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, app, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .mixin({ methods: {
                route
            }})
            .mount(el);
    },
});

InertiaProgress.init({ color: '#4B5563' });`


here is example component: 

`<template>
    <app-layout title="Values">
        <template #header>
            <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
                Our Values
            </h2>
        </template>
        <div class="py-12">
            <div class="container max-w-8xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div class="px-auto text-center">
                    <p class="text-2xl">Our <span class="font-bold">Values</span> are the behaviors that we care about the most. We Believe them. We live by them. <br>They are how we deliver on our promise to inspire and equip our team and clients to fulfill their purpose.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="grid grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-2 2xl:grid-cols-3 gap-3 mt-12 mx-4 md:mx-0">
                    <template v-for="value in value.data">
                        <div class="flex flex-col bg-primary rounded-lg p-10 md:p-12 lg:p-14" :class="{'text-white': value.company_id === 4}">

                                <h3 v-if="user.is_spanish == false || value.spanish_name == null" class="text-5xl lg:text-6xl font-bold" :class="{'font-joan': value.company_id === 3}">{{ value.name }}</h3>
                                <h3 v-else class="text-5xl lg:text-6xl font-bold" :class="{'font-joan': value.company_id === 3}">{{ value.spanish_name }}</h3>
                                <div class="bg-white w-[15%] h-1 mt-4 ml-1"></div>
                                <div v-if="user.is_spanish == false || value.spanish_description == null" class="markdown value-description mt-10 text-lg pl-4" v-html="value.description"></div>
                                <div v-else class="markdown value-description mt-10 text-lg pl-4" v-html="value.spanish_description"></div>

                        </div>

                    </template>
                    <div class="flex flex-col bg-white rounded-lg p-12">

                        <h3 class="text-5xl lg:text-5xl font-thin">Recognize a Team Member <br>for living out<br> our values.</h3>
                        <div class="h-full flex mt-6 md:mt-0"><a :href="route('shoutout.create')" type="button" class="btn !w-fit self-end">Submit a Shoutout</a></div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </app-layout>
</template>

<script setup>
import {ref, useAttrs} from 'vue'
import AppLayout from '@/Layouts/AppLayout.vue'
import EmployeeCard from "@/Components/Cards/EmployeeCard.vue";
import {GridWithTopbar} from '@/Components/Lists';
import { Form, Select, Textarea, Submit } from "@/Components/Form";

const props = defineProps({
    users: [Array, Object],
    filters: Array,
    value: [Array, Object]
})

const attrs = useAttrs();
const user = ref(attrs.user);



const options = ref([]);

</script>

I have tried deleting project re clone from production git. Npm install/update composer install/update.
Tried logging items in the vite and app.js to see if things are breaking everything seems to be working as expected.
re checked inertia which also seems to be working as expected it shows in logs that the page that should be loading should be loading but it is in fact not showing until manual refresh.

can you tell me the Vite version?
